# How can i get SeekBar value Like this?

Tags: android, seekbar

i want to create seek bar in my project, for every step i want increment like this 
seek bar maxvalue = 6;

```
seek bar value increments : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
i want seek bar values like this : 0 2 5 10 15 20 25
```

how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would store the possible values in an array and use the current seek-bar value as the element-index for accessing the "desired" value.

**Pseudo-code**

```
int[] values = {0,2,5,10,15,20,25};
int current = values[ seekbar.getValue() ];
```

So for `seekbar.getValue() == 2` your `current == 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
if((seekbar.getValue()%5)==0){

    int n=seekbar.getValue()/5;

    int seekValue=(n*5);

}
```